Differences between DJI Mavic 3 E and Mavic 3M
I would like to invest in a suverying drone under €5000 and obviously have my eye on a DJI Mavic E.
Due to having a €5000 budget, I would be in a position to afford either the Mavic 3E or the 3M. Both can be considered surveying drones due to the RTK module enabling better accuracy. The advantage of the 3M is that I would also have the near infrared sensor which could maybe be utilized in my line of work with the environmental agency in regional government. This is however not currently a requirement. But saying that...we have never had the technology available to us.
I am interested to know whether there any reasons why I would restrict myself to the 3E. Are there any disadvantages to the 3M if I am primary looking to use it for surveying or can I think of the 3M as a 3E with an added sensor?

As best I can tell (I've used a Mavic 3E, but not the Mavic 3M) the main trade-offs are the Multispectral system adds about 40g weight (which reduces flight time) and adds about €1000 to the price (based on a quick search; adding accessories - batteries, RTK module, etc. - might narrow or widen that.)
The added weight only claims to decrease flight time by a minute or two, for over 40mins of flight, which I think is probably not significant. And adding another battery to your kit would more than make up for this.
The added cost is a bit more of a personal decision based on your situation; but you say either falls within your budget and if the multispectral capability brings you more work and/or allows you to charge more, it could pay for itself.
However, as the 3M has RTK support and the same camera as the 3E, getting the 3M shouldn't reduce your 'core' survey capability. Which is to say, I think your last paragraph is correct - the 3M is the 3E with an extra sensor.
